# Qt 5.1 Android, ABI mismatch

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I have installed the recent Qt 5.1 SDK and Android NDK r8e also platform-tools for API level 10 and 17. When I now try to deploy my application to the Android device (or simulator) I always get the error

> Unable to start 'org.qtproject.example.testandroid'.

adb gives me something like

> W/PackageManager( 1481): Check ABI compatibility
>   W/NativeHelper( 1481): Native ABI mismatch from package file
>   E/PackageManager( 1481): INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE
>   W/PackageManager( 1481): Package couldn't be installed in

The target device is either a Gingerbread Android phone or a simulator with API level 10.

How can I resolve this error? Seems like this is ARMv6 phone and it uses a ARMv7 compiler. I'm running the tools on Linux.